# How to run a middleware first in a pipeline but with endpoint metadata?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, routes, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-middleware

I need to filter some of our API actions to work only from local host. Seems there are a few methods to accomplish this:

1. setup [CORS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-7.0);
2. Add an [Authorization filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-7.0#authorization-filters) or an [Action filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-7.0#action-filters);
3. Add a middleware as a first step in a pipeline.

The first 2 methods are not suitable in our case since the entire pipeline will be executed before the request is blocked and that is not desirable.

Using a middleware leads to the same result, since to filter out only certain actions/controllers marked with a specific attribute we need an endpoint metadata which is not available until `UseRouting` middleware is executed.

Is there any possibility to do this in ASP .NET Core 7.

Comment: Before get route endpoint, only way is filter with request URL path.

Comment: Wanted to stick with a sort of "code-first" approach, but seems this is the only way. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure which metadata are you talking about, but if the decision is only based on the requester origin and the request's resource path, you can write something like this:

```
// This is an inline middleware that you can put as the first in the chain
// If you decide to write a middleware class, you can inject IHttpContextAccessor to it

app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{    
    var refererUrl = context.Request.GetTypedHeaders()?.Referer?.ToString() ?? string. Empty;

    if (context.Request.Path == "allowed path" &&
        refererUrl == "allowed requester")
    {
        await next(context);
    }    

    // if the path or requester is not allowed,
    // the request will be short-circuited by not calling next(...)     
});
```

Comment: I see. So the only way to do this is to add some sort of an endpoint URL list to an external configuration (as opposed to method/controller attributes) and check that inside a middleware. Seems like an acceptable workaround. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, and I hope it works! 